# Pine script - How to get bar_index at X time in Forex market

Tags: pine-script

I'm using this to find the bar_index value at a secific time:

```
(time - mytime) / (1000 * timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period))
```

The problem is that in the Forex market those values ​​do not match, I think because of the time shifts on weekends.

How can I find the correct bar_index?
Thank you

Comment: Why do you need bar index? Where are you going to use this? Can't it be done with `ta.barssince()`, instead?

Comment: Because I need to know the RSI value at that specific point and with time I don't know hot do get it. If I had the bar_index I could do: rsi[bar_index - mybarindex]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `bar_index` to figure out a value when a condition occured, you can use the built-in function `ta.valuewhen()`.

> Returns the value of the `source` series on the bar where the
> `condition` was true on the nth most recent occurrence.
>
> **condition (series bool)** The condition to search for.
>
> **source (series int/float/bool/color)** The value to be returned from the
> bar where the condition is met.
>
> **occurrence (simple int)** The occurrence of the condition. The numbering
> starts from 0 and goes back in time, so '0' is the most recent
> occurrence of `condition`, '1' is the second most recent and so forth.
> Must be an integer >= 0.

Something like:

```
my_cond = // your condition
value_when_cond = ta.valuewhen(my_cond, rsi, 0)
```